# Disconnect Facebook and PayPal

Tags: facebook, paypal

Somehow I have got in a situation where whenever I use PayPal to pay for something it sends me a message on Facebook. I want to cancel my PayPal account and my Facebook account but before I would do so, I figured there would be a way to fix it. However, the web doesn't seem to offer any help.

I tried this:

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Settings/FB-Messenger/td-p/1143603

However, when I got to the relevant page in Facebook there was nothing labeled PayPal. There was one payment method with an icon that was a triangle over three vertical bars over a horizontal bar. No idea if that is PayPal, no tooltips or other information. However, I clicked Remove anyway and got a message saying "Sorry we were unable to remove your payment method. Please try again later."

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Here are two links, look if they help you: [First](https://www.facebook.com/help/242462812536016), [Second](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Settings-Archive/How-do-I-remove-my-Paypal-account-from-Facebook/td-p/637435)

Comment: Some other third-party that's bridging the two? I seem to recall there was a social app that would broadcast your purchases. Some sort of self-control booster. (Unfortunately, the name escapes me.) I'd check to ensure that the apps you have connected to your PayPal and Facebook accounts are ones you really want to have.